# Do self-answers count toward the Lifejacket and Lifeboat badges?

Tags: support, badges, lifejacket-lifeboat-badges

I'm writing up the [badge criteria FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/377214) and it's unclear in the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) as to whether or not self-answers are considered towards the Lifejacket and Lifeboat badges.

If I answer my own negatively-scored question, it later goes on to earn a positive enough score, and my self-answer scores highly enough, do I earn these badges?

Comment: If there is something unclear in the question, or if I missed something in the blog post, it would be very kind if I knew what it was so I can improve my question. If you believe that it shouldn't be awarded to self-answers and disagree with what this question asks about, wait for an answer here, and if it's that it *is* awarded to self-answers, file a feature request asking that it not be.

Comment: Somebody apparently hates lifejackets/lifeboats. I've checked if there is any information available about the Red Baron type hats and self-answers, but zip. Next Sunday we might be able to infer some statistics from SEDE (though it doesn't know which post you earned a badge on, but it might limit the # of badges we need to check).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you do indeed. Or at least, [I did](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/102/lifejacket?userid=2085):

[image: example of lifejacket on elu.meta question]

for [this answer to my own question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/proposal-to-add-small-capitals-formatting-directive/5484#5484).